# WP Gravity Forms API - Updating entry status

Tags: php, wordpress, api

This is specific to Gravity Forms + Gravity Flow. I'm using their GFAPI to update entry status from "Processing" to "Paid", however, if I do that manually via WP Admin panel in gravity forms, then it works fine and the workflow of Gravity Flow advances to next step, but if I do it with code like this:

```
$entry = GFAPI::get_entry(“193”);
$entry[“payment_status”] = “Paid”;
$entry[“is_fulfilled”] = “1”;
$result = GFAPI::update_entry($entry);
return $result;
```

then on entry it says that it has been paid, but workflow won’t advance to next step. I am using form submission between two forms. When the entry with payment is paid, it should go back to the first form and advance it forward, it doesn’t. Any idea why?

Comment: Looks like you have copied this code from somewhere else with font quoted. You can try that code by replacing the normal quote.

Comment: No, I wrote this code myself and it shows normal quotes in where the actual code sits, no idea why it copied like this, but that's not the problem since the status does get updated, it changes, just won't advance the workflow like it's supposed to.